# Excel VBA to write only rows with text to txt file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table (Table8) that I need to export as .txt file.
The code I'm currently using works fine but also exports empty rows from the table which messes up the .txt file for further use.

The table will have information in 1 to n rows (usually not more than 100). 
I would like to only export those rows, which have text in them (other rows have a formula in them and currently appear as blank in .txt file).

Code I'm currently using:

```
Sub saveToMtext()
    Dim filename As String, lineText As String
    Dim myrng As Range, i, j

    filename = ThisWorkbook.path & "\textfile-" & Format(Now, "ddmmyy-hhmmss") & ".txt"

    ChDir (ThisWorkbook.path)
    Open "m_text.txt" For Output As #1
    FileFormat = xlText & CreateBackup = False

    Set myrng = Range("Table8")

    For i = 1 To myrng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.Count
            lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & vbTab) & myrng.Cells(i, j)
        Next j
        Print #1, lineText
    Next i

    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Just check with an IF if the cell is empty or not. Please, note that a cell with a formula that returns a blank **is not** an empty cell,so maybe you could instead check the len of the value returned, or another trick.

Comment: I added length measure for a cell inside the For loop with an If statement but it keeps popping up an error "Next without For"

For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.Count
        LValue = Cells(k + 1, 121)
            If Len(LValue) > 1 Then
            lineText..... 

Can't If be used inside For loop like this?

Comment: Yes it can be used, but if your code is not properly indented, then it causes that error. Post it.

Answer (score 1):

I changed from regular IF to IF x Then Exit For and got it working.

Final code:

```
Sub saveToMtext()
    Dim filename As String, lineText As String
    Dim myrng As Range, i, j
    Dim LValue As String

    filename = ThisWorkbook.path & "\textfile-" & Format(Now, "ddmmyy-hhmmss") & ".txt"

    ChDir (ThisWorkbook.path)
    Open "m_text.txt" For Output As #1
    FileFormat = xlText & CreateBackup = False

    Set myrng = Range("Table8")
    k = 11

    For i = 1 To myrng.Rows.Count
        LValue = Cells(k, 121)
         m = Len(LValue)
            If m < 1 Then Exit For
        For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.Count
            lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & vbTab) & myrng.Cells(i, j)

        Next j

        Print #1, lineText
   k = k + 1
    Next i

    Close #1
End Sub
```